# Can hreflang be used for city-specific content?

Tags: local-seo, hreflang

I know that I can use `hreflang` for country specific content in order to avoid duplicate content, but what about *city* or *state* specific content?

Is that possible, and if not, how do I deal with it?

Comment: I think for city specific content you may need to look into geolocating, however the issue would be as to how accurate the data would be as going purely on ip address would be a bad idea

Comment: yes thats a problem, geolocation works well for countries and languages but cites?? How would I do that accuratly :(

Comment: have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202077/high-accuracy-geolocation-html5 not sure but this maybe something to look into

Comment: yes i was thinking about that, geolocation might be the way to go, however that requires user permission. as for gps im mainly after desktop users with this. thanks for the link though,

Comment: See my answer here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49627/is-there-a-way-i-can-redirect-search-engine-traffic-by-u-s-state-or-zip-code/49630#49630

Comment: thx. i guess its not possible with hreflang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rel="alternate" hreflang="x" annotations cannot be used to specify a city, or any other geographical content other than the Language and region:

[hreflang supported values](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)

> The value of the hreflang attribute identifies the language (in [ISO
>   639-1 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)) and optionally the region (in [ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2))
>   of an alternate URL. For example:

I doubt it ever will either, as it doesn't really make sense to have duplicate content on your city specific pages, Google would want you to make them unique. You should make your city specific pages unique to that city, adding some info about the city and write about your location in that city. (e.g, if you were a franchise store, write about that particulars stores history)